# Error "subscript requires array or pointer type" but everything works?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

This is my first time asking questions here, but I've gotten help by seeing answers to others people's questions here so I was hoping I could get some answers to a problem I was having too.

So I'm testing out 2d arrays and was thinking of making a cool project (My first one ever) where I use 2d arrays as my so called `Screen`. With this I decided to make a print screen function where it would print out each integer of each array and then go on to a new line. Now it does do this fine, but I keep getting the error in the title on line 11 (aka `std::cout << Screen[i][j];`) with the red squiggily line under i.

Sorry if I don't format this correctly, but hopefully someone can explain what's wrong!

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>

void refreshScreen(int Screen) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            std::cout << Screen[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int Screen[5][5] = {
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0}
    };

    refreshScreen(Screen[5][5]);

    return 0;
};
```

With the output of

00000
00000
00000
00000
00000

Comment: in `refreshScreen` `Screen` is a single value not an array. `refreshScreen(Screen[5][5])` is passing a single element (which is out of bounds of the array) not the whole array

Comment: I would use `std::array` here.  Then it's a first-class object and you can pass it around like any other (by `const` ref, in this case).

Answer (score 3):

If you want `refreshScreen` to accept a 5x5 array, you can change it to:

```
//---------------------------vvvvv---
void refreshScreen(int Screen[][5]) {
   // ...
}
```

Or alternatively to:

```
//---------------------------vvvvvv---
void refreshScreen(int Screen[5][5]) {
   // ...
}
```

Both will work and the compiler will not really care about the first dimension but I find it more expressive (and self documenting) to use the explicit size.

Then when you call the function, you should pass only the name of the array:

```
refreshScreen(Screen);
```

(passing `Screen[5][5]` means a single element, which is not even valid in this case since indices should be in the range 0..4).

See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q43PqTbjn).

**A side note:** since you use c++ you can consider to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for dynamic size arrays).

Comment: Should the parameter not be `Screen[][5]`? As it stands, OP will think that what you've shown is a valid/correct way to pass arrays. The first dimension should be specified in a new argument. I mean, technically it works, but C++ doesn't care about the first dimension value.

Comment: @sweenish that's exactly what I wrote in the note below the demo link. But I will edit and make it more explicit.

Comment: Updated the answer. BTW I prefer to specify the first dimension even though the compiler doesn't care about it. I believe it signals the caller what they should pass to the function.